# Excel formula for previous weekday

Tags: excel, function

I have a macro in which asks user for a date and it opens the file corresponding to the date and performs some operation. However, instead of entering the date manually I am trying to write an excel function to calculate the previous weekday. This is because the date I usually enter corresponds to the previous weekday.

For example, if today is Monday, I want last week's Friday date- and for the rest of the weekdays upto Friday, it's just the previous day. There won't be files corresponding to weekends.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Which format is your date? Is it Excel date format or just text value with weekday?

Comment: @Taosique: It's in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: I mean, how is the date passed to your macro/function? Like a Date type variable which in fact is Integer? Or as a text?

Comment: @Taosique: I enter the date in mm/dd/yyyy format only through a UI or it reads from the cell A1 in the same format.

Answer (score 5):

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)
```

This returns the serial number for the day in Excel, which can just be formatted in the cell.

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-function-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33) for the full explanation of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Excel 2010 or later:

```
=IF ( WEEKDAY (A1, 16) > 3 , A1-1 , A1 - WEEKDAY (A1, 16) )
```

Adding `16` as the second parameter of `WEEKDAY` sets Saturday = 1.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA:

```
Public Function PreviousWeekDay(InputDate As Date) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Result = Weekday(InputDate, vbMonday)
    If Result = 6 Or Result = 7 Or Result = 1 Then
        Result = 5
    Else
        Result = Result - 1
    End If
    PreviousWeekDay = Result
End Function
```

Returns 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(NOW()-2)>5,NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW()-6),NOW()-1)
```

Then just format the cell however you want it displayed

Comment: @MatthewHagemann what are those magic numbers -2,5,-6,-1 supposed to mean? If you add the explanation to your answer you may get my vote

Comment: Sorry.  I need to get better at the explanations.  In data serialization, 1 = a day.  So Now()-2 would be the day before yesterday.  What the formula is doing is saying if yesterday was Saturday or Sunday (2 days ago being Friday or Saturday), we want the date of the previous Friday returned (you could accomplish this by subtracting the next weekday's number from today, hence Weekday(Now()-6) or Weekday(Now()+1)) .  If that is not the case, it simply returns yesterday's date.